# VS code resolve conflicts view

Tags: visual-studio-code

In recent update vs code changed resolve conflicts view.
How can return to old view like in their docs?

New version Image

[image: 1]

Link to docs
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_merge-conflicts

Comment: have you ever tried searching SO, you are number 20 asking the same question

Answer (score 0):

Deselect the following Option:

Git:Merge Editor
Open the merge editor for files that are currently under conflict

[image: Merge Editor]